# signjar doesn't support the "sigalg" attribute with OSX java version "1.6.0_37"

Tags: java, macos, ant, sign

I have updated my MAC this week and received a new Java Version. 
java version "1.6.0_37"

Now ANT complains about not being able to sign JARs anymore

```
signWebStartJars:
   [delete] Deleting: /Users/swagner/Documents/workspaces/openmeetings_zz/Openmeetings/build/filetest.keystore
   [genkey] Generating Key for filetest
   [genkey] Erstellen von Schl?sselpaar (Typ RSA, 1.024 Bit) und selbstunterzeichnetem Zertifikat (MD5withRSA) mit einer G?ltigkeit von 90 Tagen
   [genkey]     f?r: CN=Sebastian Wagner, OU=technology, O=incubator.apache.org/openmeetings, C=DE
   [genkey] [/Users/swagner/Documents/workspaces/openmeetings_zz/Openmeetings/build/filetest.keystore wird gesichert.]

BUILD FAILED
/Users/swagner/Documents/workspaces/openmeetings_zz/Openmeetings/build.xml:449: signjar doesn't support the "sigalg" attribute
```

My java version is now:

```
Administrators-MacBook-Pro:Openmeetings swagner$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_37"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_37-b06-434-11M3909)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.12-b01-434, mixed mode)
```

This is the ANT script:

```
    <signjar alias="filetest" keystore="${keystore.file}" storepass="secret" lazy="false"
        sigalg="MD5withRSA" digestalg="SHA1">
        <path>
            <fileset dir="${screenshare.out.dir}">
                <include name="**/*.jar" />
            </fileset>
        </path>
    </signjar>
```

Did somebody resolved this already? 
It did not happen before the OSX update.

Thanks!

Sebastian

Answer (score 1):

You need to update to at least ant 1.8.3.

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/incubator-openmeetings-user/201209.mbox/%3CCAJmbs8gEpsL2g2NjWGRWoOeHJy9MP5d+715_5Bgo0=j_r1n9TQ@mail.gmail.com%3E

Download the latest ant from: http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi and update the symbolic link at /usr/bin/ant to the extracted ant file from the download.

Comment: If you're running linux (as I am), here's a great straightforward tutorial on how to install ant from the site: http://toub.es/2012/10/02/manually-installing-ant-184-ubuntu-1204 ...just change their version number to whatever you're installing.

Answer (score 0):

The 'sigalg' attribute was added to the Ant 'signjar' task quite recently. You must have switched to an older version somehow.